# Replace string regardless of the value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How can I replace this string with another one regardless of whether the value is 2 or 4 or 5

```
<font size=\"2\"
```

I have it now :

```
replacingOccurrences(of: "font size=\"2\"", with: "font size=\"4\"")
```

But a 2 by default does not always arrive.

Comment: A NSRegularExpression could do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)` with `.regularExpression` options.

```
let str = "<font size=\"3\""
print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "(font size=\"[0-9]+\")", with: "font size=\"4\"", options: .regularExpression))
```

> ```
> <font size="4"
> ```